# Can a Scout use Dual Weapon Attack after attacking with a two-handed weapon?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons, class-feature

I've been working on building a scout using spiked chain training.

The main hand part of the spiked chain is a weapon with the "stout" keyword, meaning it can be used as a two-handed weapon. Can I make a two-handed attack with the main-hand weapon and then follow that up with Dual Weapon Attack with the offhand part of the weapon?

The context here is that I'd like to use the Power Attack feat to make the first attack with the bigger damage bonus. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, you *can't* use Dual Weapon Attack after attacking with a (normal) two-handed weapon

**Yes**, you *can* use Dual Weapon Attack after attacking with the `stout` end of a double weapon

From the Adventurer's Vault Errata (emphasis mine):

> *Stout:* A weapon that has the stout property **can be treated as** a two-handed weapon.

Basically, whenever you *want* it to count as a two-handed weapon, it counts as a two-handed weapon. Obviously, you want it to count as a two-handed weapon for the purposes of the Power Attack feat but not for the purposes of the Dual Weapon Attack ability, so that's how it works. It isn't a two-handed weapon; you're still dual wielding for all intents and purposes, including triggering Dual Weapon Attack. But if you want an attack with the main-hand end to count as being made with a two-handed weapon, it does.

TLDR: The `stout` end of a double weapon is essentially a "two-handed" weapon that can be wielded in one hand, as long as you wield the other end in your other hand.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the compendium, the entry for Stout simply says that it can be used two-handed. Versatile weapons use the same language, saying that they can be used two-handed. I don't have access to rulebooks here, but I believe it is a Free action to switch modes. This would mean that you could switch from two-handed weapon to double weapon as needed, assuming you could take free actions (i.e. not Dazed or Stunned).

Having said that, Dual Weapon Attack has a Requirement of 'You must be wielding two weapons', and its trigger is 'You hit with a melee basic attack...' - I believe the two combined together would stop you from using the weapon the way you wish. At the point when you hit, you would not be wielding two weapons, and so Dual Weapon Attack could not be triggered.

Comment: How do a pair of wrist razors change the situation?